# Measure the electricity consumed by a browser to render a webpage

Tags: energy

Is there a way to calculate the electricity consumed to load and render a webpage (frontend)? I was thinking of a 'test' made with phantomjs for example:

- load a web page
- scroll to the bottom

And measure how much electricity was needed. I can perhaps extrapolate from CPU cycle. But phantomjs is headless, rendering in real browser is certainly different. Perhaps it's impossible to do real measurements.. but with an index it may be possible to compare websites.

Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: I'm wondering why you need this information? Surely there's a better metric for what you're trying to test?

Comment: Just the electricity used by the computer it's running on? What about the monitor? What kind of storage is being used? What sized power supply? I'm not sure this is a question for SO.

Comment: I want to create an service similar to https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/ but that measure the energy efficiency of the front-end (Because it's easy to measure your backend, just check your electricity bild). Like I say it can be an index based on the average for example. So yes I want to measure only what the browser need to render a specific page.

Comment: Forget it, what you want to achieve is essentially impossible. Taylor Kidd's answer should give you a pretty good idea of how difficult it is to measure on your own machine that you have total control of. Running it as a web service that relies on software-only methods to get an accurate and precise reading is (as good as) impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much impossible to measure this internally in modern processors (anything more recent than 286). By internally, I mean by counting cycles. This is because different parts of the processor consume different levels of energy per cycle depending upon the instruction.

That said, you can make your measurements. Stick a power meter between the wall and the processor. Here's a procedure:

1. Measure the baseline energy usage, i.e. nothing running except the OS and the browser, and the browser completely static (i.e. not doing anything). You need to make sure that everything is stead state (SS) meaning start your measurements only after several minutes of idle.
2. Measure the usage doing the operation you want. Again, you want to avoid any start up and stopping work, so make sure you start measuring at least 15 seconds after you start the operation. Stopping isn't an issue since the browser will execute any termination code after you finish your measurement.

Sounds simple, right? Unfortunately, because of the nature of your measurements, there are some gotchas.

Do you recall your physics classes (or EE classes) that talked about signal to noise ratios? Well, a scroll down uses very little energy, so the signal (scrolling) is well in the noise (normal background processes). This means you have to take a *LOT* of samples to get anything useful.

Your browser startup energy usage, or anything else that uses a decent amount of processing, is much easier to measure (better signal to noise ratio).

Also, make sure you understand the underlying electronics. For example, power is VA (voltage*amperage) where both V and A are in phase. I don't think this will be an issue since I'm pretty sure they are in phase for computers. Also, any decent power meter understands the difference.

I'm guessing you intend to do this for mobile devices. Your measurements will only be roughly the same from processor to processor. This is due to architectural differences from generation to generation, and from manufacturer to manufacturer.

Good luck.

Comment: It's also pretty likely that the amount of energy used in the monitor will far overshadow the processing power needed by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Yes, if the energy monitor is on the computer (motherboard, power supply, etc) and taking its energy from the same wall socket. He should use a monitor that is a separate unit placed in between the wall socket and the computer. And you're right, the energy used by the monitor will be a lot bigger.  :-)   (Is there a way we can measure current and consume only uA?)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't think of simply measure it... That's not true than monitor use lot more power than CPU: http://blog.codinghorror.com/revisiting-how-much-power-does-my-laptop-really-use/ (so yes making script more efficient save energy)

Comment: Interesting article but a little out of date (2008). There is a whole lot of improvement due to the implementation of new standards (e.g. device sleep states) and new technologies (e.g. more advanced C-states). What tangrs and I were talking about is a little different, namely the difference in energy usage. The processor may use ~30W but the difference when scrolling might be <10uW. A power meter must measure current as well as voltage. If the voltage is 120V, then the meter would need to use <<10u/120 A. I don't know how this can be done.