# Measure energy consumption in java

Tags: java, virtual-machine, energy

I have already searched for the answers but no one seems to have an exact answer for my problem. I want to measure the energy consumption of a virtual machine when a java program or any program is executed in virtual machine. Also it would be great if we can measure the energy consumption of each core in virtual machine. What plugin in Java can be used to gauge the energy consumption of a Virtual Machine ?

Comment: *energy consumption of each core in virtual machine* - A virtual machine is **virtual** it doesn't have *cores*. Instructions are always executed on the physical cores (hyper threading might create an illusion - make you believe that there are 2 X NumberOfPhysicalCores but eventually, every instruction will have to hit one of those physical cores

Comment: I mean to say how can we measure energy consumption of each physical core when a multi threaded java program is executed in virtual machine ?

Comment: What if the same core is shared by multiple processes / threads?

Comment: That's not a problem. I just want a method to calculate energy consumption of a core.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you can measure the energy of a virtual machine.

I'm assuming you want to measure the energy of a virtual machine along with the program it is executing (if there is one). (Finding the energy consumption of a virtual machine -- e.g. JVM -- by itself and not including the program executing on it is much much more difficult.)

There are several ways to measure the total energy from the JVM.

1. You can measure from the wall. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997297/measure-the-electricity-consumed-by-a-browser-to-render-a-webpage/34002308#34002308).
2. Use JNI to drill down under the JVM and use the PAPI* APIs.
3. Use JNI to drill down under the JVM and use the [platform dependent hardware PMU event counters](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/5/2/c/f/1/30320-Nehalem-PMU-Programming-Guide-Core.pdf).
4. Use the underlying kernel data structure or APIs.

In all cases, the most accurate results are going to be averages across several samples / test runs. There's a lot going on in a computer system, and much of it is intermittent, such as garbage collection, interrupt processing, and virtual machine supporting background processes.

The disadvantage of #1 is that it needs external hardware. In addition, it includes *everything* such as external peripherals, memory, etc. You'll want to compute the difference in energy usage.

The disadvantage of #2 is that the PAPI APIs are just APIs and their implementation is hidden. Since supported processor HW events are in flux, many PAPI APIs measure things indirectly and can give only very approximate results.

The disadvantage of #3 is that the PMU events are hardware dependent by definition. The PAPI APIs are an attempt to solve this issue. Also, earlier processors often didn't have energy PMU events.

The disadvantage of #4 is similar to that of #2.

Good luck.

*PAPI as in [Performance Application Programming Interface](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/), and not the [Java access control API](http://papi.rediris.es/).

Comment: Reading the papi site, they say they have Java APIs as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Java is *secure*. It protects your from integrating too much with your real hardware. I could suggest you not to use Java. You should use some system language (bash script for example) to get metadata from your hardware and then write it to something that Java can easily read (file, socket, etc).